# How to set Timezone to the logged in user timezone using groovy in jira

Tags: groovy, timezone, jira

Can anyone help with the groovy methods to set timezone to the logged in user in Jira

Comment: please provide more details to your question. what have you tried so far and what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do it in ScriptRunner. Hope this code explaining enough.

Also you can change default timezone for all users through General configuration page in admin section of Jira.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.user.preferences.PreferenceKeys

// First of all get you timezone name
// You can define it through plaintext also if you know right values
me = getUserByName("mylogin")
timeZoneToSet = ComponentAccessor.getUserPreferencesManager().getExtendedPreferences(me).getString(PreferenceKeys.USER_TIMEZONE) 

// Then find users which you want to change
// I don't know you criterias and just add this findAll for example
usersToChange = getAllUsers().findAll{it.getEmailAddress().contains("my.domain")}

// Then let's do this and change timezone for these users
for (user in usersToChange) {
    setTimeZoneForUser(user, timeZoneToSet)
}

def getUserByName(String userName) {
    ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getUserByName(userName)
}

def getAllUsers() {
    ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getAllUsers()
}

def setTimeZoneForUser(user, String value) {
    ComponentAccessor.getUserPreferencesManager()
        .getExtendedPreferences(user)
        .setString(PreferenceKeys.USER_TIMEZONE, value)
}
```

Comment: I am getting below error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: timeZoneToSet for class:

Comment: Are you sure that you define timeZoneToSet and it contains string value of timezone?